# Can't get height and width from FilePath to Bitmap

Tags: android, image, file

I'm currently trying to compress my image : here is my image :

> /data/user/0/com.clearmindai.trainer/files/facebookimaged.jpg

This is my compress method :

```
public static String compressImage(Context context, String imageUri, String fileName) {
        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(context, imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;


        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;
        }
```

the actualHeight and actualWidth returns 0 which i clearly don't know why.

This is how i call it :

```
  ImageUtils.compressImage(
                            this, imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), "fitbook_image")
```

Let me know if i need to add more code for clarification. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out below code it will work

```
bmp.getheight() or bmp.weight()
```

try this the methods are available